# How to define functions of functions

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to define a function, call it "L", which itself is a function of other functions, such as:

L[x[t], y[t]]:= x'[t]+y'[t]

Then, I want to take a derivative of L[x[t], y[t]] with respect to t.

I really thought I'd be able to figure this out quickly, but no luck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Something like `L[x_, y_, t_] := D[x, t] + D[y, t]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
L[x_[t_],y_[t_]]:=x[t]+y[t];
```

Then

```
D[L[x[t],y[t]],t]
D[L[Sin[t],Cos[t]],t]
....
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

L[x_, y_] := D[x, t] + D[y, t]

L[x[t], y[t]]

(* Derivative[1][x][t] + Derivative[1][y][t] *)
```

To take the derivative

```
D[#, t] & /@ L[x[t], y[t]]

(* Derivative[2][x][t] + Derivative[2][y][t] *)
```

or

```
D[L[x[t], y[t]], t]

(* Derivative[2][x][t] + Derivative[2][y][t] *)
```